# Document contains in a list/counter

Tags: javascript

If a use a dom command like this:

```
document.contains(document.querySelectorAll('div#my#item div')[1].querySelector('a').innerHTML)
```

I receive this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'contains' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.(…)
```

How can I fix my query to receive true or false?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here, check if the element exists, or get the HTML ?

Comment: the result is returned by document.querySelectorAll, so it has to be in document logically. what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Also, `document.querySelector('#item div a').length > 0`

Comment: @adeneo you mean `querySelectorAll` ?

Comment: @Sachin - in this case no, finding one element is enough

Comment: so if this is already one element then why are you checking length on it? @adeneo

Comment: @Sachin - `document.contains` determines if the node is in the document, but if `querySelector` returns an element, i.e. the length is over zero, the document clearly contains one or more such elements, so there's no need to look for more elements, we already know the collection has length

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns an element and `document.querySelectorAll()` returns an array. and an element doesn't have length property, so `document.querySelector().length` is undefined. try your code, this element is not collection. @adeneo

Comment: @Sachin - now you're on to something, and that is correct, when using  `querySelector` I should've used `... !== null` to see if it returns something, not `.length > 0`, so +1, didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `innerHTML`

```
document.contains(document.querySelectorAll('div#my#item div')[1].querySelector('a'));
```

`contains` [checks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) for a node not html string